# How to send a request from express to mongodb to delete multiple record from collections

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Delete multiple record from mongodb collections using angular and express.

How I can send array of ids from express to mongodb.

Here is code for deleting single todo from mongodb in express

```js
 app.delete('/api/todos/:id', function(req,res){
        Todos.remove({
            _id: req.params.id
        }, function(err, todos){
            if(err)
                res.send(err);
            Todos.find(function(err, todos){
                if(err)
                    res.send(err)
                res.json(todos);
            });
        });
    });
```

#### angular controller code

```
$scope.deleteTodo = function(id){
    $http.delete('/api/todos/'+ id).then(function(response){
        var data = response.data;
        $scope.todos = data;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy approach is to re-use your route by just passing comma-separated list of IDs e.g. `/api/todos/id1,id2,id3`.

```
app.delete('/api/todos/:ids', function (req, res) {
    Todos.remove({
        // convert string of IDs to array of IDs
        _id: { $in: req.params.ids.split(',') }
    }, function (err) {
        if (err) return res.send(err);
        Todos.find({}, function (err, todos) {
            if (err) return res.send(err)
            res.json(todos);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: It will work for static ids, how to do it by passing array of  ids from angular controller to middleware express controller

Answer (score 0):

> How I can send array of ids from express to mongodb.

In this example I show you how to make an array from the parameter and using underscore each loop we iterate over the array of ids to delete one by one.

```
app.delete('/api/todos/:id', function(req,res){
  try{ //:id can be a list of ids separated by ','
   var deleteID = req.params.id.split(','); //array is made
   // Temp. Error Log
   var errorCount = 0; var errorLog = '[ERROR LOG]\n';
   // Delete each ID
   _.each(deleteID,function(this_id,index){
     Todos.remove({id:this_id},function(err,todos){
      //errors occuring while deleting, stored into temp log
      if(err){errorCount++;errorLog+="\n["+index+"]\n"+err;}
     });
   });
   // Check if any errors happened
   if(errorCount!=0){ // RETURN ERRORS :
    res.send(errorLog);
   }else{ // NO ERRORS :
    Todos.find(function(err, todos){
     if(err){res.send(err);}
     else{res.json(todos);}
    });
   }
  }catch(e){res.end(); console.log(e);}
});
```